# Could not run migrations using sqlite

Tags: php, laravel

When i run the command `php artisan migrate` it gives me this error:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
> Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432? (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

In as much as i am using a `database.sqlite` file for my database

My .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed by doing the following:

I added the path for my database file in my .env, then it looked like this below

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite 
DB_DATABASE='database/database.sqlite'

Then I cleared my cache using  `php artisan config:cache`

Then I ran `php artisan migrate` and it worked!